# convert integer key values in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have data in a dictionary that is nested inside a Python list as shown below. What I am trying to do is convert some integer values from Degrees Celsius to Degrees Fahrenheit but I know I am doing some wrong in trying to save the converted the temperature value.

```
data = [{'gas_station/headquarters/12032/Space Temperature Local': 21.368864059448242,
         'gas_station/headquarters/12033/Space Temperature Local': 22.3087215423584, 
         'gas_station/headquarters/31/ZN-T': 71.94377136230469, 
         'gas_station/headquarters/29/ZN-T': 72.39180755615234, 
         'gas_station/headquarters/12028/Space Temperature Local': 22.77256202697754, 
         'gas_station/headquarters/27/ZN-T': 71.6547622680664, 
         'gas_station/headquarters/30/ZN-T': 69.44559478759766, 
         'gas_station/headquarters/26/ZN-T': 71.9398422241211}, 
         {}]

for key, value in data[0].items():
    if value < 40:
        #print(key, value)
        print(f'*** [INFO] *** -  Celsius found values on {key} is {value}')
        value = (9/5) * value + 32
        print(f'*** [INFO] *** -  New converted temp is {value}')
```

I am doing something wrong in saving the new converted deg C to deg F temperature data to the original list/dictionary data type. Would anyone have a suggestion? If I print the original `data` again the original temperature units are present.

```
for key, value in data[0].items():
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: Instead of assigning to the variable `value`, assign to the dictionary value using `data[0][key] = (9/5) * value + 32`

Comment: geez well that was an easy one, thank you still learning : ) If you post an answer ill hit the green check

Comment: No bother, glad it helped though! and happy learning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't assigning the value back to the `dict`. If you want to stick to your loop, do this:

```
data[0][key] = (9/5) * value + 32
```

Separately, you might consider using dict comprehension instead of looping

```
data[0] = {key: (9/5)*value+32 if value<40 else value for key,value in data[0].items()}
>>> data[0]
{'gas_station/headquarters/12032/Space Temperature Local': 70.46395530700684,
 'gas_station/headquarters/12033/Space Temperature Local': 72.15569877624512,
 'gas_station/headquarters/31/ZN-T': 71.94377136230469,
 'gas_station/headquarters/29/ZN-T': 72.39180755615234,
 'gas_station/headquarters/12028/Space Temperature Local': 72.99061164855956,
 'gas_station/headquarters/27/ZN-T': 71.6547622680664,
 'gas_station/headquarters/30/ZN-T': 69.44559478759766,
 'gas_station/headquarters/26/ZN-T': 71.9398422241211}
```

Comment: Any chance you could help me understand `Separately, you might consider using dict comprehension instead of looping`? Non-computer science guy here, does looping consume more memory and slower than dict comprehension? It looks like there is a loop inside your dict comprehension... Thank you for any high level insight, especially your extra comment for a better practices to learn : )

Comment: For some reason the list comprehension doesnt save the converted temperature data to the original data

Comment: You need to assign it back to `data[0]`. Edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah thanks Ill have to read into comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't save it to the dictionary. Try following,

```
for key, value in data[0].items():
    if value < 40:
        #print(key, value)
        print(f'*** [INFO] *** -  Celsius found values on {key} is {value}')
        value = (9/5) * value + 32
        data[0][key] = value
        print(f'*** [INFO] *** -  New converted temp is {value}')
```

Answer (score -2):

except putting their comma you should try 'and'

```
for key and value in data[0].items():
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: your answer makes no sense

Comment: @MARTIAN Y - You are definitely wrong. `for key and value` isn't even correct syntax. Please test your code before posting.